# Is it possible in Intellij IDEA Scala plugin to know which implicit conversion was applied?

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, implicit-conversion

When an implicit conversion is applied, IntelliJ underlines the converted code. Is it possible to navigate to the applied conversion in some way?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Yes **it is possible** (IntelliJ IDEA 11.1.3 CE with Scala Plug-In 0.5.948, but this has been possible for a while).

You need to select the *receiver* not the method itself. For instance, assume `dataDir` is of type `java.io.File`. Then I can do

```
dataDir.listFiles().foreach( ... )
```

where `foreach` is available through implicit conversion from `Array` to `ArrayOps`, thus is underlined. If you select `dataDir.listFiles()` and choose from the menu Navigate -> Implicit Conversion (shortcut `Ctrl-Q`), a popup menu shows you all possible conversions, and **selects the conversion currently applied**.

[image]

Comment: +1, you are right. However the shortcut is Ctrl+Shift+Q, at least on my machine (Ubuntu) ;-). I'll delete my answer as soon as it's unaccepted (can't do it now).

Comment: I'm on OS X. There was a problem with the shortcut before, because it was occupied by an OS-wide function, that's probably why it got changed. Indeed, the current version has an _additional_ defunct shortcut `Alt-Return` :-/

Comment: WOW, a year of work without knowing it existed. I was always looking for the implicits manually, thanks

Comment: How do I know which one is actually used in the list? There are so many and I have to check them one by one :(

Comment: @Freewind the one that is initially selected in the list, that's the one applied.

Comment: There are more details [on this IDEA wiki page](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IntelliJIDEA/Working+with+Scala+Implicit+Conversions)

Comment: There is also another option: selecting the value, pressing Alt+Return and selecting `Provide implicit conversion` intention will make the used implicit conversion explicit.

Comment: Very cool.  I just need to determine which implicit is applied, without IntelliJ, in the REPL.  `:t` does not give the answer.  Any ideas?  Thanks

Answer (score 12):

As above but the shortcut in Windows/Linux is **Ctrl+Shift+Q**.